# Python type hinting for List with possible values

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function:

```
def foo(a, b):
  return [a, b]
```

I want to add type hinting for return value, as you can see my function can return `[srt, int]` or `[str, str]` or `[int, int]` etc. for example.

I tried:

```
def foo(a, b) -> List[str, int]:
  return [a, b]
```

but it not working.

How can I specify possible value in list that my function can return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union). Specifically, `Union[X, Y]` means either X or Y.

```
from typing import List, Union

def foo(a, b) -> List[Union[str, int]]:
    return [a, b]
```

If your function can return a list containing any element, then use [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) (special type indicating an unconstrained type):

```
from typing import Any, List

def foo(a, b) -> List[Any]:
    return [a, b]
```